# "Information is temporarily unavailable." message in google gadget editor

Tags: javascript, xml, google-gadget

When this .xml file:
http://www.pikefin.com/phpdev/table.xml

is previewed in the google gadget editor (here's a link to the gadget editor:
http://www.google.com/ig/directory?type=gadgets&url=www.google.com/ig/modules/gge.xml)

I receive the following error message: "Information is temporarily unavailable."

Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the following line is removed:

```
 <Require feature="locked-domain"/>
```

then it works.